# What is the best practice with adding static field name in cshtml View in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have question.

In my project, I used two method to adding static field in View.
First: I created in my attribute model Display:

```
[Display(Name = "Saturday", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Calendars))]
public bool Saturday { get; set; }
```

Second: Adding from resources directly in View:

```
<div class="row cells12 height-inputlike">
    <div class="cell colspan2 padding-top05">@Resources.Models.Calendars.Saturday</div>
    <div class="cell colspan3 padding-top05">
        <label class="switch-original">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Saturday)<span class="check"></span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

How the difference between these processes, and which is better in the context of building a large application?

Or is there a better way?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer the `[Display]` attribute. The reason is that the built-in validation then can also use the translated label in the error messages it generates (e.g. "Saturday is required").

You can render the label using the `Html.LabelFor(m => m.Saturday)` helper.

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful for me